# Image file get rename and path get changed from assets to dist

Tags: webpack, angular5

I am building my `angular 5` application using following command :-

> "webpack --config=webpack.config.js

while building what it does that , the .png files which have higher dimension more then 100*100 it will rename that file and put in current `dist` directory and the png images which have dimension less then 100*100 will remain in that assets folder.

At run time it will take smaller dimension file from `assets` and larger dimensions file  from `dist` .

so at run time it try to load that image file from `dist` with following URL :-

> file:\c:\angularApplication\dist\index.html\abc.128024hoh233232.png

Image file is present in the `dist` directory but the URL is Wrong so it give me error that `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

and when I am changing the dimension from i.e. make it less than 100*100 ,
application load that image from `assets` folder.

Does anyone have idea about this strange behavior.